# Как отсортировать товары в корзине Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы добавленные товары в корзину отображались отсортированные по категории и наименованию. А также отсортированные приходили в бланке заказа на почту?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать повесить сортировку на хук "woocommerce_cart_contents_changed"

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_changed', function ( $cart_items ) {
    // тут сортируем массив 

   return $cart_items;
} );
```